# How to interpolate value in one array based on another array (combining scipy interp1d with np percentile)

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation, percentile

If I have two numpy arrays, what is the cleanest way to interpolate the value of `x` that corresponds to a specific percentile in `y`, when array `y` is an NxM array?

For example,

```
x = np.array(
    [
        97,
        4809,
        4762,
        282,
        3879,
        17454,
        103,
        2376,
        40581,
    ]
)


y = np.array(
    [
        [
            0.14,
            0.11,
            0.29,
            0.11,
            0.09,
            0.68,
            0.09,
            0.18,
            0.5,
        ],
        [
            0.32,
            0.25,
            0.67,
            0.25,
            0.21,
            1.56,
            0.21,
            0.41,
            1.15,
        ],
    ]
)
```

I was hoping a combination of scipy interpolate and numpy percentile would work, but it seems scipy has an issue with the array dimensions.

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(y, x, axis=0) 
f(np.percentile(y, 50, axis=0))
```

returns `ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.`

Expected return is [0.09, 0.21].

Comment: How did you get [0.09, 0.21]? Those are the middle values of y (`y[:, y.shape[1]//2]`), but y isn't sorted. The 50th percentile (median) of y along axis 1 is [0.14, 0.32], which corresponds to 97 in x.

Comment: @yut23 Sort by x, use same sorting (indexing) in each y. 50th in x is 3879. For each y, that sorting yields 0.09 and 0.21, respectively, in y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `x` and `y` mixed up in the code. This should do what you want:

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
f(np.percentile(x, 50))
```