# How can I use scipy interp1d with N-D array for x without for loop

Tags: function, numpy, lambda, scipy, list-comprehension

How can I use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) when my `x` array is an N-D array, instead of a 1-D array, without using a loop?

The function `f` from interp1d then needs to be used with [`numpy.percentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) with one of the arrays as an input.

I think there should be a way to do it with a list comprehension or lambda function, but I am still learning these tools.

(Note that this is different than my recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72107658/how-to-interpolate-value-in-one-array-based-on-another-array-combining-scipy-in) because I mixed up the `x` and `y` arrays in the posted question, and this problem was not reproducible.)

*Problem statement/example:*

```
# a is y in interp1d docs 
a = np.array([97,4809,4762,282,3879,17454,103,2376,40581,])
 
# b is x in interp1d docs 
b = np.array([
        [0.14,0.11,0.29,0.11,0.09,0.68,0.09,0.18,0.5,],
        [0.32,0.25,0.67,0.25,0.21,1.56,1.60, 0.41,1.15,],]
)
```

Just trying this, below, fails with `ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.` The expected return is `array(97, 2376)`. Using median here, but will need to consider 10th, 90th, etc. percentiles.

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(b, a, axis=0)
f(np.percentile(b, 50, axis=0))
```

However this, below, works and prints `array(97.)`

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(b[0,:], a, axis=0)
f(np.percentile(b[0,:], 50, axis=0))
```

A loop works, but I am wondering if there is a solution using list comprehensions, lambda functions, or some other technique.

```
l = []
for _i in range(b.shape[0]):
    _f = interpolate.interp1d(b[_i,:], a, axis=0)
    l.append(_f(np.percentile(b[_i,:], 50, axis=0)))
print(out)
# returns
# [array(97.), array(2376.)]
```

*Efforts*:

I understand I can loop through the `b` array with a list comprehension.

```
[b[i,:] for i in range(b.shape[0])]
# returns
# [array([0.14, 0.11, 0.29, 0.11, 0.09, 0.68, 0.09, 0.18, 0.5 ]),
# array([0.32, 0.25, 0.67, 0.25, 0.21, 1.56, 1.6 , 0.41, 1.15])]
```

And I also understand that I can use a list comprehension to create the scipy function `f` for each dimension in `b`:

```
[interpolate.interp1d(b[i, :], a, axis=0) for i in range(b.shape[0])] 
# returns 
# [<scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d at 0x1b72e404360>,
#  <scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d at 0x1b72e404900>]
```

But I don't know how to combine these two list comprehensions to apply the `np.percentile` function.

Using Python 3.8.3, NumPy 1.18.5, SciPy 1.3.2

Comment: Please use ~1 line per row for your arrays. This is not JSON

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is formatted by [black](https://github.com/psf/black), is this not the standard for python?

Comment: It certainly isn't for numpy data arrays. It's incredibly annoying to read the rows of a matrix vertically, and it makes your code take up 10x more space than it needs to. For lists, especially containing objects, this format makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I've reformatted if to show a much more conventional appearance.

Comment: Also, the standard is PEP-8. Black is just a formatting tool. From what I see so far, it's not one I'd ever care to use.

Comment: `axis=1` regardless of anything else

Comment: Also, it'd be a lot more clear if you called your arrays `x` and `y` to signal your intent.

Comment: `f = interpolate.interp1d(b[0,:], a, axis=1)` returns `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. `axis=0` produces expected answer

Comment: Sorry, for the 2D case. `axis` is the dimension containing the data vector. For the 1D case of course it's 0, since there are no other axes.

Comment: ``f = interpolate.interp1d(b, a, axis=1)` still throws tuple index error`

Comment: As well it should, since it's not designed to operate that way. But that doesn't excuse using the wrong axis. Compare `np.percentile(b, 50, axis=1)` to `np.percentile(b, 50, axis=0)`

Comment: As it happens, you are massively overthinking this problem.

Comment: Here, b = x in scipy intep1 and a = y. Using these arrays and `f = interpolate.interp1d(b[0,:], a, axis=0)` then `f(np.percentile(b[0,:], 50, axis=0))` produces the desired result: `array(97.)`. Similary,  using `[1,:]` produces the desired result: `array(2376.)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large data arrays, you want to stay away from `for` loops, `map`, `np.vectorize` and comprehensions. They will all be slow. Instead, it's always better to use vectorized numpy or scipy operations whenever possible.

In this particular case, you can implement the vectorization pretty trivially yourself. [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) defaults to a linear interpolation, which is very simple to code by hand. For a general interpolator, the first step would be to sort x and y, which is why scipy can't support multiple `x` for a given `y`. If the `x` rows all have different sort order, what do you do with the `y`?

Luckily, there are a couple of things you can do to make this much faster than having to build a full interpolator or [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) `y` multiple times. For example, start by argsorting `x`:

```
idx = b.argsort(axis=1)
```

`idx` is now an array such that `b[np.arange(2)[:, None], idx]` gives the sorted version of `b` along axis 1, and also, `a[idx]` is the corresponding `y`-values. Since you are taking the median (50th precentile), and the rows have an odd number of elements, the value of `x` is just the middle of each row, and `y` is given by

```
a[idx[:, len(a) // 2]]
```

If you had an even number of elements, you would have to average the elements surrounding the middle:

```
i = len(a) // 2 - 1
a[idx[:, i:i + 2]].mean(axis=1)
```

You can reduce algorithmic complexity by using [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) instead of a full-blown `np.argsort` to get the middle element(s).

Comment: This returns `IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2` on `a[idx[len(a) // 2]]`
Also, is it readily extensible to other percentiles? I am using np.percentile for a reason, that's why it's in the OP, I want to look at other percetiles

Comment: @a11. Yes, it's readily extensible. You just have to interpolate different indices

Comment: @a11. Sorry, I forgot the `:, ` in the first example. Got it right in the second. Fixed now. If you have a bunch of different percentiles, please edit the question to add more information. Are the percentiles random, structured in some way, able to only take on a small set of values, only drawn from a particular range?

Answer (score 0):

interp1d and other interpolators from scipy.interpolate only support 1D x arrays. So you'll need to loop over the dimensions of x manually.